# Database connectivity with RDS in AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, database-connection, rds

I'm trying database connect RDS using Mysql to save form value in RDS. I'm using the below code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($_SERVER['RDSEndpointwithport'], $_SERVER['username'], 
$_SERVER['password'], $_SERVER['databasename']);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
die('Mysql connection error');
}
else{
echo "Connection Established";
}
```

It shows error i.e.
Failed to connect to MySQL: No such file or directoryMysql connection error

Comment: check RDS instance `inbound` connection

Comment: Are they in the same vpc ? Or is the RDS multi-availability zone? Did you add the instance to the RDS's security group?

Comment: Troubleshooting: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.Connecting